# How to install pyfoam pip/python with different versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, openfoam

I installed pyfoam as:

`pip install PyFoam`

According to https://pypi.org/project/PyFoam/ .
Now, I try to use pyFoamVersion.py and I got this message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/bin/pyFoamClearCase.py", line 4, in <module> __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('PyFoam==2021.6', 'pyFoamClearCase.py') File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3251, in <module> @_call_aside File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside f(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set working_set = WorkingSet._build_master() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master ws.require(__requires__) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'PyFoam==2021.6' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

I tried this:

`pip --version pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)` 
and

`python --version Python 2.7.18`

How to solve this mess?

Comment: For one thing, stop using Python 2.7

Comment: it requiring specific 'PyFoam==2021.6' try force reinstall or install like this
just do 'pip install PyFoam==2021.6'

Comment: Also maybe python version. Absolutely important note by @Reinderien

Comment: I tried using python3 and everything worked just fine. Maybe you should just upgrade to python3